# django.fcgi or virtualenv : no module named operator

Tags: python, django

## So these are my website informations:

- framework : Django
- hosting : alwaysdata
- python : 2.7
- virtualenv is used

---

## The problem :

I have the non explicit 500 error :

```
Internal Server Error
```

I have not any error log

### But :

I found a trail to solve this issue. Indeed when i run manually the django.fcgi, i got this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "public/django.fcgi", line 14, in 
    from django.core.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi
  File "/home/usr/.virtualenvs/thevirtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/fastcgi.py", line 17, in 
    from django.utils import importlib
  File "/home/usr/.virtualenvs/thevirtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 4, in 
    from django.utils import six
  File "/home/usr/.virtualenvs/thevirtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 23, in 
    import operator
ImportError: No module named operator
```

---

## Manipulation(s) which could occur this issue :

I had this issue for 3 week ago, i let it rest too long, so now i can't remember what i have done to bring about this.. But i think it was a dirty virtualenv creation or edition, something like that..

Thanks to bear with my english.

Does anyone have an Idea about my case?

## Attempts to solve this issue:

I just tried to recreate my virtualenv and got this error message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/usr/python/python27/bin/virtualenv", line 5, in 
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available
```

Comment: You should probably post the full traceback+error message

Comment: Ok, there is now full traceback with error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `operator` module is part of the standard library, it looks like you have a corrupt Python installation in your virtualenv. The best thing to do would be to simply delete and recreate your virtualenv.

Comment: thanks, i tried this but got an error message: see it in my question that i just edited.

Comment: i just made a complete reset of my configuration (bash_profile, python installation, virtualenv etc..)
It seems to be working fine now, thanks.