# ImportError: No module named operator

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm rather new to using python and haven't done really anything to configure python. my professor gave us an autograder.py file that checks our python code for correctness. the autograder.py file imports a file called grader.py which then imports something known as cgi (import cgi). inside this cgi file located at '/usr/lib/python2.7/cgi.py' there is a line of code that says

```
from operator import attrgetter
```

this is where the problem occurs. i recieve the following error

> ```
>      Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "autograder.py", line 12, in <module>
>         import grading
>       File "/home/ggkfox/Documents/164-CSCI/1-Assignment/tutorial/grading.py", line 13, in <module>
>         import cgi
>       File "/usr/lib/python2.7/cgi.py", line 37, in <module>
>         from operator import attrgetter
>     ImportError: No module named operator
> ```

it is my understanding that the operator module should be built in (according to other stack overflow posts). this error only occurs when i use python2.7.12 (as opposed to python3.5). i have had a simular issue importing Tkinter in 2.7 aswell.

also i want to say that i have tried uninstalling python using:

```
sudo apt-get purge python2.7
```

but it wont even uninstall for me to even attempt to reinstall. im not using any pipenv or desktopenv.

i dont know what else to say, im very new to python coding.

Comment: As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22452380/2996101), you may try to delete and recreate the virtualenv.

Comment: i saw that post before, but i didn't think it was applicable because im not using a virtualenv. i just downloaded the file i had to edit, then ran it.

Comment: A virtualenv will create a "dedicated to your project needs" python environment. I cannot imagine starting a project outside a virtualenv because it really saves you from os related troubles. I am currently using [virtualenvwrapper](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/#virtualenvwrapper) but this is only one choice from the linked doc page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is almost a necessity to use a virtualenv for each python project.

A virtualenv creates a dedicated python environment and it saves you from a lot of 'operating system' related issues.

[Here](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/), you can find some virtualenv solutions compatible with all Python versions, along with the [official python 3.6.4 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html).